# Disabling paging in Huawei

Tags: cli, huawei

I'm interacting with a `MA5616 Huawei`, and paging is enabled by default. So for a command like `display adsl port state all`, I'll be asked if I'd like to see more results.

Is there anyway to disable this behavior, paging, and receive the result at once? Per command, or even better for the whole session.

Comment: You can increase number of visible lines by using `scroll N`, but the maximum number is 512. Please post an answer if you found a way to set this property to unlimited.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: @RonMaupin, There is only one answer and that doesn't help. Also my own comment isn't an answer, it's just a workaround. I think it doesn't have any other solution.

Comment: That's fine. I have just been trying to clean up any questions that have answers where none are accepted. If there are no acceptable answers, you do not need to accept one. Also, if you have discovered that there is no answer, then that could be the answer, and you could answer it and accept the answer.

Answer (score 5):

```
screen-length 0 temporary
```

Accroding to [cisco to huawei](https://pleiades.ucsc.edu/hyades/Cisco_vs_Huawei_Commands) cheatsheet I stumbled upon.

Worked for me on *VRP (R) software, Version 5.170*. There are probably many other Huawei boxes with different command sets, or this functionality may not be available at all.

Answer (score 0):

MA5608T model has no command 'screen-length'. To disable paging use:

```
config
mmi-mode enable
quit
```

Help describes this command as "machine-machine interaction mode".

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation to your answer.

Answer (score -1):

set screen-length 0 on user-interface you are using.